# Neo4j Bolt: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure

Tags: security, authentication, neo4j, bolt, neo4j-desktop

I have a  Bolt Authentication issue that I don't know how to solve. I restored a backup from my online provider to my local machine. I can launch the browser and run "`CALL db.schema`" and the query returns. But when i try to just select a sample set of data I'm seeing this in the logs and the query never returns.

```
2018-06-25 14:39:23.778+0000 ERROR Unexpected error detected in bolt session 'ace2d3fffe92e75d-0005b714-00000004-4c1990029792d052-f94315d8'. The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltConnectionFatality: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.handleFailure(BoltStateMachine.java:742)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.handleFailure(BoltStateMachine.java:728)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.access$500(BoltStateMachine.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine$State$1.init(BoltStateMachine.java:435)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.init(BoltStateMachine.java:145)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.BoltMessageRouter.lambda$onInit$0(BoltMessageRouter.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.MetricsReportingBoltConnection.lambda$enqueue$0(MetricsReportingBoltConnection.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:195)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.MetricsReportingBoltConnection.processNextBatch(MetricsReportingBoltConnection.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.executeBatch(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:170)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.lambda$scheduleBatchOrHandleError$2(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In my config file I can turn off security: `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` and things will work. But I'd like to understand why/how I'm getting this error so I don't have to do that. In the administration tab of the desktop I've tried changing the password and it says it's successful but the error still remains?

Comment: It might be that existing Bolt connections are still active after changing a password. Have you tried stopping and restarting the neo4j Browser?

Comment: No luck in restarting the instance. I can have the database shutdown, do the password change, restart the desktop, start the database, open new browser. I can connect but I can't query the data.

Comment: I also just tried dropping and recreating the 'neo4j' user which is my admin user and I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring to an identical version resolves issue. So good knowledge to have, back ups must be restored to identical versions. Or at least v3.3.5 restored to 3.4 will present this issue.

Comment: Did you just reinstall the same version and re-create your db?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did